# csslint cli running in rhino gets stuck (win7)

Tags: java, javascript, cmd, rhino, csslint

I am trying to get the csslint - cli ( https://github.com/stubbornella/csslint ) to run on my system (windows 7).

After typing in `java -jar rhino\js.jar csslint-rhino.js styles.css` and hitting enter nothing happens.

Version numbers are all up-to-date. I am running the CMD as an admin.

Below you can see what my CMD shows me when i am trying to start csslint. Also you can see all the relevant version numbers:

[image: cmd]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems to work in older versions of rhino. 
rhino1_6R7 in my case...